# finding the number of elements in a defaultdict(list) python

Tags: python

A quick question? I am wondering if there is a pythonic way to get the following.

I have a defaultdict(list)

```
 foo = {"a":[1,2,3], "b":[3]....} and so on.
```

Is there a pythonic way to write a function which returns me only the keys whose list have length more than "n"

so for example

```
 def return_keys_based_on_value_length(num,dictionary):
    key_list = []
    for k,v in dictionary:
         if len(v)>= num:
            key_list.append(k)
    return key_list
```

is there a pythonic way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foo = {"a":[1,2,3], "b":[3], "c":[1,2], "d":[1,2,3,4]}

n = 2

my_list = [key for key,val in foo.iteritems() if len(val) > n]
```

Result:

```
>>> my_list
['a', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 2
foo = {"a":[1,2,3], "b":[3]}
key_list = [item for item in foo.keys() if len(foo[item]) > 2]
```

Results in `['a']`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the filter function:

```
filter(lambda x: len(dictionary[x])> num, dictionary.keys())
```

Comment: I  do not think that filter is best to use if you need it also for map.